# Getting value from MVC3 Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webclient

So, I have an action on a controller in my MVC3 website that I'm using as a service.  The return type is string, and I'm wondering what would be the best way to consume this?

```
public class HomeController : Controller {       
    public string GetSomeValue(){          
        return "This is some value";      
    }  
}
```

Should I use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class, and if so, what method would be best suited for this?  I've never used this class before and it looks a little hairy?

This question is part 2 of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267333/mvc3-action-as-a-simple-web-service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use WebClient or the WebRequest object if you want to call your service from the server.

If you just want to read a string you could use it like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.yoursite.com/Home/GetSomeValue");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @slfan.  This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought that perhaps my question wasn't clear after reading the first two answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are asking the correct way to return a string, but here it is:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {       
    public ActionResult GetSomeValue(){          
        return Content("This is some value");      
    }  
}
```

In terms of consuming it, I'd use [Restsharp](http://restsharp.org/) and make the action simply return a Json string:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {       
    public ActionResult GetSomeValue(){          
        return Json("This is some value");      
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to return a string value from controller method.

then simple use either

```
public ActionResult YourMethod(){
or 
public JSONResult YourMethod(){
............
return JSON(new {retunrvalue = "My Text"}, JSONRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```